# Laravel 4 Cannot find Class DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

**Problem:** I'm trying to bootstrap L4 framework for some files (php-resque workers at `app/workers`) to use, but the workers dont seem to be able to find the class `DB` on a line that used `DB::table('tablename')...`. `composer dumpautoload` does not help.

Did the bootstrap I'm using not load the `DB` classes? It seemed to have loaded the worker classes.

**Failed L4 Bootstrapping**

```
<?php

// Bootstrap the laravel environment for our resque workers.
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

**error**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DB' not found in /var/www/dev/app/libraries/test.php on line 50
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "chrisboulton/php-resque": "@stable"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/libraries",
            "app/workers"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": "php artisan optimize"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to:

1) Load the Composer autoload file, located in `vendor/autoload.php` (you are actually calling the laravel one)

2) Replicate the calls in the `public/index.php` file in your `test.php` file, specifically:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
$app->run();
$app->shutdown();
```

Edit: after further inspection, you could try to do this with a bare minium:

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB;
// Test the DB Instance
$dbInstance = new DB;
var_dump ($dbInstance);
```

will output

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB)[2]
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of doing `$app->run()` then `$app-shutdown()`

Comment: Basically, the `$app` object returned by the `require_once` directive, returns an instance of `Illuminate\Foundation\Application`.

Comment: Sorry, the comment got truncated, i was writing:

.....omissis....

If you take a look inside that class(/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php), you'll see that the `run` method (~line 446) is responsible to dispatch the request to the router array.

After further inspecting, ended up you could simply 

`require_once '<path to>/vendor/autoload.php'; // load the composer autoload`
`require_once '<path to>/bootstrap/start.php';`
`// Test the DB Instance`
`$dbInstance = new DB;`
`var_dump ($dbInstance);`
to have it loaded without bootstrapping the whole framework.

Comment: @thinkers I am having similar issues could you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527586/unable-to-call-illuminate-class-from-resque-worker